# Checking for errors in batch script / Finding strings

Tags: batch-file, findstr

How can I find and compare more than one sets of strings in batch in order to check for errors???
I know how to do it with one set of string:

```
FINDSTR /C:"successful" someFile.txt && (ECHO It was successful.)|| ECHO It failed.
```

Here it looks for the word "successful" in that someFile.txt and prints out the 1st echo if it finds the string, the 2nd echo if it can't find the string.
Now, I want to search for not only 1 but 2 or 3 sets of words/strings at once. Is that possible?

Comment: What's wrong with calling `FINDSTR` more than once?

Comment: @DocBrown, nothing is wrong with using FINDSTR more than once. I just wanted to see if it was possible what I wanted to do in a more organized fashion, than have bunch of FINDSTRs again n again. Learning never hurts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, the best way here is to use those conditional execution commands properly. Or, like @DocBrown said, use the FINDSTR several times.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using the `/C` option to `findstr` you can list several, space-separated words to look for:

```
findstr "foo bar baz" someFile.txt
```

would search for one of `foo`, `bar` or `baz`.

Comment: @duper: I was assuming you meant "more than one **set** of strings", as you wrote, not "more than one string" (which, I guess, you already know).

Comment: @DocBrown, thanks for the help! :) Initially, that was what I meant. But, everything is working now.